# I can't dequeueReusableCell when the Cell is in its own class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to move my "cell" code from the "func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)" function to its own class. I have registered the forCellReuseIdentifier and class with the ViewController (I think). And I have set the reuseIdentifier for the prototype cell to "MealSelector". However, when I run the code, all of the cells are blank. Why is the data not populating the tables?

Here is the view controller:

```
import UIKit

class MealSelectorController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var MealTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var ConfirmOrderButton: UIButton!
var recipes: [[String?]] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    for _ in 0 ..< 3 {
        let recipe: Recipe = APICaller.getNewRecipe()
        self.recipes.append([recipe.title, recipe.description])
    }

    MealTable.dataSource = self
    MealTable.delegate = self
    
    MealTable.register(MealSelectorCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MealSelector")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.recipes.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MealSelector")
    
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 241
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

}

Here is the cell:

```
import UIKit

class MealSelectorCell: UITableViewCell {


override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: What _is_ your issue? You have not told us what the problem is.

Comment: The cells are just coming out blank. It is not using my prototype cell at all to build the TableView

Comment: The cell is blank because you don’t put anything in it. Where would it get any contents? You create an empty cell, dequeue the empty cell, return an empty cell. Nothing you have shown us makes the cell anything but empty. Looking at your code, I would expect to see a big empty cell. If you are seeing that, your code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, you say:

> It is not using my prototype cell at all to build the TableView

If that means a prototype cell in a storyboard, then delete this line:

```
MealTable.register(MealSelectorCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MealSelector")
```

That line means: Do *not* use the storyboard prototype. So you will need to delete it.

You will also need to set the class of the prototype cell in the storyboard.

However, I would then expect your app to crash because your `init(coder:)` implementation says to crash.

```
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
```

You’ll probably want to fix that too...